# Trigger notification bar from <p:ajax> event

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I'm looking to trigger a notification bar on checkbox click using `<p:ajax>`. The notification bar would have the save option to save data in the database. The **update** atribute within `<p:ajax>` doesn't seem to work. It's been quite a research, but couldn't derive at a solution. Am I missing something here ? I'm using **JSF 2.1+Primefaces 3.5**.  Any help would be much appreciated.

**xhtml page**

```
<p:column headerText="#{msgs.ref}" styleClass="menuHeader textAlignLeft">
    <p:notificationBar widgetVar="customSaveBar" position="top" styleClass="saveBar warningBar textAlignCenter" style="height: 25px;padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0;" effect="none" rendered="true">
          <h:outputText value="There are pending changes on the page." styleClass="warningText"/>
          <h:outputText value="&#160;"/>

          <p:commandLink action="#{abcDashboardBean.abcDTOValues}"
           onclick="skipPageRedirectWarning = true;showPleaseWait();"
           styleClass="warningText" id="saveFromBar"
           onsuccess="customSaveBar.hide()"
           oncomplete="placeRemoveIcon();"
           update="@form"
           process="@form"
           value="#{msgs.save}"/>
     </p:notificationBar>
     <p:selectBooleanCheckbox styleClass="margin_left_10" value="#{abcDto.refBl}"
                            rendered="#{!authorizationBean.userADMIN or !authorizationBean.userPM or !authorizationBean.userINDM}">
        <p:ajax event="click" partialSubmit="true" update="customSaveBar"></p:ajax>
    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>

</p:column>
```

**abcDashboardBean.java**

```
public Map<Object, Boolean> getAbcDTOValues(){
    Map<Object, Boolean> map = new LinkedHashMap<Object, Boolean>();

    //fill the map with the items defaulted to unchecked
    for (AbcDTO abcDTO: abcList){
        map.put(abcDTO.getPpcCode(), Boolean.FALSE);
    }
    Abc abc1 = dataAccessEjbService.find(Abc.class, abc.getId());
    saveAbcRefChanges(map, abc1);
    return map;
}

public void saveAbcRefChanges(Map<Object, Boolean> map, Abc abc) {
    for (Map.Entry<Object, Boolean> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().equals(true) && abc != null) {
            abc.setReferenceBl(true);
        } else {
            abc.setReferenceBl(false);
        }
    }
    dataAccessEjbService.update(abc);
}
```

**AbcDTO.java**

```
private boolean refBl;

// getters + setters
```

Comment: Just to be sure: your `p:selectBooleanCheckbox` is inside a `h:form`?

Comment: Did you inspected the XHR requests to see if there's any error? (you can see them right-clicking in your browser and entering in the `inspect` mode)

Comment: @OscarPérez - thanks for highlighting to check if the code is within the `h:form` tag. But that's not the case !!
in the logs, I get an error saying "*component `customSaveBar` cannot be referenced from `p:selectBooleanCheckBox`

Comment: I see what the problem is: `customSaveBar`is the `widgetVar`, not the `id`. This means that you have a Javascript widget named `customSaveBar`, but you cannot reference it from a faces side. Just add `id="customSaveBar"` to your `<p:notificationBar` and it should work!